# Convert (Nested List) Objects based on another variable's type

Tags: dart, casting

In my code, I'm creating a grid of objects. I'm trying to avoid duplication by abstracting away the loop that creates the grid and passing the specific object from outside. For example:

```dart
List<List<dynamic>> _createGridWithSameElements({
  int height,
  int width,
  dynamic element,
}){
  List<List<dynamic>> vanillaGrid = [];

  for (int heightIndex = 0; heightIndex < height; heightIndex++){
    List<dynamic> vanillaLine = [];
    for (int widthIndex = 0; widthIndex < width; widthIndex++){
      vanillaLine.add(element);
    }
    vanillaGrid.add(vanillaLine);
  }

  return vanillaGrid;
}
```

Then, if I wish to create a grid with string, I can:

```dart
List<List<dynamic>> emptyGrid = _createGridWithSameElements(
  height: height, 
  width: width, 
  element: Cell.dead()
);
```

However, I would like to somehow recast the individual, atomic elements of the grid based on the type of the `element`. I think I have two options, neither of which I have been able to achieve:

1. Infer the type inside `_createGridWithSameElements`. But how would I do this without using `List<List<dynamic>>`?
2. Recast the grid after the `_createGridWithSameElements` function call. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Generics](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics) to create an argument that can hold any type.

Don't forget to also, instead of passing the element itself, passing a function to generate instances of it. Otherwise you will have a grid containing the same repeated instance.

```dart
class Cell{}

void main(List arguments) {
  final grid = _createGridWithSameElements(
    height: 5, 
    width: 10, 
    elementGenerator: () => Cell()
  );

  print(grid.runtimeType); // List<List<Cell>>
}

List<List<T>> _createGridWithSameElements<T>({
  int height,
  int width,
  T Function() elementGenerator,
}) {
  final vanillaGrid = <List<T>>[];

  for (int heightIndex = 0; heightIndex < height; heightIndex++) {
    final vanillaLine = <T>[];
    for (int widthIndex = 0; widthIndex < width; widthIndex++) {
      vanillaLine.add(elementGenerator());
    }
    vanillaGrid.add(vanillaLine);
  }

  return vanillaGrid;
}
```

Some extra info to keep in mind:

- The `<T>` after the function name is there to tell Dart to make `T` available as a generic type for that function. Any letter or word would be valid, though `E`, `T`, `S`, `K`, and `V` are the convention.

Comment: I'm gonna try it soon. Is this `T` a generic placeholder for any type?

Comment: Yes, the method does declare T as a generic type with `_createGridWithSameElements<T>`. The Dart type system is often smart enough to guess what type you want so in this case, Dart will determined the result type based on the type of the `element` argument.

Comment: Just to confirm it, the `vanillaGrid` and the `vanillaLine` have to be `final`s because their types will be figured out during runtime, right? Also, what's up with the `<T>` at the end of `_createGridWithSameElements`? Btw, `Cell.dead()` is a factory constructor for the `Cell` class.

Comment: I added `final` on them because I normally want to post Dart code which follows the rules defined in the extra_pedantic package. Since the type can be automatically determined we don't need to write the type but can just write `final` (since the variable as also not gonna be changed). About `<T>` you should read about generics: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

Comment: I should add that the solution right now uses the same object instance for all elements in the grid. This is not really a problem for Strings or objects which has a constant state. But if the object allows modifying the internal state then it affect all points in your grid since all points refer to the same object. If you instead want to create a new object for each point then please tell me and I can modify the code to do that. :)

Comment: If you have a handy way of doing that, I would really appreciate it (I imagine something like passing in a function as argument that would get called to build the element, instead of passing the element itself). With respect to my previous question: is the `<T>` after the function name for declaring that it is used as a generic type by the function. The linked docs are not very clear on that part still.

Comment: Yes, you just need to change the argument to take a function instead and then call for each element you add to the grid. The generic part still works since Dart can see the return type of the function and use that to determined the type of List. And yes, the `<T>` after the function name are used to declare that `T` can now be used as a generic type inside the function. You can use any letter or word. I just used `T` here.

Comment: Thank you very much. Wonderful help :)